# How to reset Lightroom's library?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-3

In Adobe Lightroom 3, how can I reset the library? That is, I want to remove all photos from the library.

Comment: You can simply create a new catalog to start fresh with an "empty" one. A catalog is really just a folder on disk with a bunch of metadata files. You could delete that folder and create a new one. I would recommend just creating a new catalog, though, just in case you want to load up your old one again and not lose the modifications and photo metadata stored in it.

Comment: Is there a way to delete a catalog?

Comment: As jrista said, just delete the folder on your computer.  There is no command inside Lightroom to delete a catalog as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The catalog is an *.lrcat file. If you delete it will be gone.** The next time you start Lightroom tell you it cannot find the catalog and will create a new one.

There is also usually a folder called Backups next to it which contains backups of your catalog. You will also find a folder called *.previews.lrdata which is a cache which you can delete anytime, even if you do not delete the catalog. That contains previews which are created as needed.